# Run multiple cURL requests in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl

I am able to execute the below cURL request (generated in PostMan) through a Git Bash in windows, and receive a response as expected.

```
curl -X GET \ https://test.amazon.com/production/john.stones \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer dfgjdrjkdrt' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: 53a3fs9a-5ce3-10fe-7f0a-33e9695ec514' \
  -H 'referer: king'
```

I wish to run multiple cURL requests, around a thousand like the above, with the name being the value that changes in each request. I tried placing them into a batch file but each line is taken as a command, so a bit unsure as to how to structure them. Anyone know how I can run multiple cURL requests, either in sequence or parallel, in Windows 10?

Comment: Run a `For` loop to read each line of a text file, _(each containing the changeable value)_, then replace the `name` in your `cURL` command with the relevant metavariable.

Answer (score 0):

I have addressed this by listing each cURL request in a batch file, replacing all single quotes with double and removed all '\' generated in Postman to divide headers. Only after this does windows run the requests successfully.